What do American people call the classes that students go to after school for SATs?
What do American people call the classes that students go to after school for SATs? In Taiwan, we call it a cram school, but there is no such phrase in any American dictionary. Could Americans please tell me what you call the classes or schools? Thank you.

Note that such classes aren't as common in the US as they are in many Asian countries.  In particular, while SATs might be given throughout mandatory education, colleges generally only care about the last set of exams... which you can take multiple times, and chose which one to submit after you have the scores.  Cram school in general isn't as much of a thing.

In my experience (growing up in California, but I think this holds anywhere with a large Asian population), there is a whole industry of after-school SAT tutoring aimed specifically at Asian students. See e.g. https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/25/magazine/asian-test-prep-centers-offer-parents-exactly-what-they-want-results.html . So I would imagine that a lot of them are mainly talked about in non-English languages, even in the US.

@Clockwork-Muse That is simply not true in this day and age in the US. When I was in HS they were not common, today they are.

It's probably true that they're not as common as in many Asian countries, but they are indeed pretty common. As you start looking at higher income brackets, unsurprisingly they get much more common.

SAT prep courses or classes

SAT prep courses or classes

That's the bottom line for a term.
We don't say cram school, though we do cram for exams.

For completeness, cramming for exams usually means waiting until the night before the exam to study for it. The metaphor is that you're squeezing all your studying into a short period of time instead of spreading it out.
